# Why am I getting " kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property binding has not been initialized " when binding is initialized?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I'm new to kotlin and android development.

I'm currently learning fragment and how to create it, receive data from one fragment and display it on another through the activity that connects them.

What I have done:

1. I created two fragment
2. I called them in the main activity dynamically
3. I used viewBinding
4. I created an interface called fragmentAactionListener in the SendingTextFragment and it has a method that will be defined in the main activity but called from the SendingTextFragment

What I was hoping to achieve:

When someone type a name in the editView and click the send button, it will call the method defined in the main activity and it will pass it to the DisplayFragment.

But when I type a name and click the button but the application class and say kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property binding has not been initialized but initialized it.

The error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.fragmenttest, PID: 5187
    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property binding has not been initialized
        at com.example.fragmenttest.DisplayFragment.recieveName(DisplayFragment.kt:31)
        at com.example.fragmenttest.MainActivity.onButtonClick(MainActivity.kt:37)
        at com.example.fragmenttest.SendingTestFragment.onButtonClicked(SendingTestFragment.kt:52)
        at com.example.fragmenttest.SendingTestFragment.onViewCreated$lambda-0(SendingTestFragment.kt:46)
        at com.example.fragmenttest.SendingTestFragment.lambda$g_0sTs_brBZ0HIBdlZHmgd8vecI(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.fragmenttest.-$$Lambda$SendingTestFragment$g_0sTs_brBZ0HIBdlZHmgd8vecI.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

My code:

The MainActivity

```
package com.example.fragmenttest

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
import com.example.fragmenttest.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : FragmentActivity(), SendingTextFragment.FragmentActionListener {

    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding
    private var displayFragment : DisplayFragment? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        var sendingTestFragment = SendingTextFragment()
         displayFragment = DisplayFragment()

        addFragment(sendingTestFragment)

    }

    // add fragment
    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment){
        // get the fragment manager and start fragment transaction
        var fTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fTransaction.replace(R.id.FLFragment, fragment)
        fTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
        fTransaction.commit()
    }


    override fun onButtonClick(name: String) {
        displayFragment!!.recieveName(name)
        addFragment(displayFragment!!)
    }
}
```

The SendingFragment

```
package com.example.fragmenttest

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.example.fragmenttest.databinding.FragmentSendingTestBinding
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat


class SendingTextFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding : FragmentSendingTestBinding
    private var activityContext : SendingTextFragment.FragmentActionListener? = null
    private var simpleDateFormat: SimpleDateFormat? = null

    interface FragmentActionListener{
        fun onButtonClick(name : String)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        activityContext = context as FragmentActionListener
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentSendingTestBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
        binding.time.text = simpleDateFormat?.format(System.currentTimeMillis())

        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            onButtonClicked(it)
        }
    }

    private fun onButtonClicked(view: View){
        if (activityContext != null){
            activityContext?.onButtonClick(binding.name.text.toString())
        }
    }



}
```

The Display

```
package com.example.fragmenttest

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import com.example.fragmenttest.databinding.FragmentDisplayBinding

class DisplayFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding : FragmentDisplayBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentDisplayBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }

    fun recieveName(name : String){
        binding.name.text = name
    }
}
```

Comment: `displayFragment!!.recieveName(name)` that's not how fragments (or activities) work. you're trying to tell it what to show before it's shown

Comment: You cannot alter fragments views just because you made an instance of it. Until fragment transaction is finished and it enters `RESUMED` state it haven't gone through lifecycle methods (`onCreate`, `onViewCreated`) and so it doesn't have view hierarchy. Also you should follow [`ViewBinding`s documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments) and make a nullable backing field instead of lateinit property as right now you will leak view hierarchy when your fragment gets detached.

Comment: Thanks for the responses but what should I do here "displayFragment!!.recieveName(name)" instead?

Comment: Please if you can explain what you me, That will be better because, I don't understand what you have said or have any idea what you're trying to say

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I have figured it out with the help of God. What I did was I removed the lateint from the binding and set it null until the the view was created, and on the recieveName function, I just received the value from the mainActivity and stored it to a variable. So when the fragment was fully created, In the lifecycle, I checked if the variable I used to assign the variable and if it wasn't null then I created the view on the DisplayFragment. I just learnt alot now. Thank you Jesus